# Path to image needs either single or double slash and I can't control when

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, path, server

I am currently programming in PHP on a server. But when uploading images to my web space and showing them I sometimes need

```
 myaddress.com//image.jpg
```

and sometimes

```
 myaddress.com/image.jpg
```

It seems to switch from time to time. Why is that and how can I fix it? I have two pages that loads with ajax directly when choosing them in the navigation bar. And when I use // it works on one of the pages and when using single / it works on the other. Why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use only one slash. Try putting full path to file and/or domain with protocol (http://myaddress.com/image.jpg)

Comment: I have tried to add the full path every time an image is displayed but it still doesn't work. I got the image work on both pages but then I uploaded another image and that image required me to use // instead of every / in the path. But all the old image still worked... :(

Comment: If an image is displayed, what is your problem? if you need to ensure it's only single slashed, you can use str_replace('//, '/', $imagePath);

Comment: Because different images requires different addresses in terms of single or double slashes. If I just try to view the image directly in the browser some images needs // and some needs /. Which is very problematic when I try to make a website that upload images...